# How could I see applications' Upload/Download speeds

Tags: internet

I'd like to see the list of those programs' Upload/Download speeds that are connected to the internet so I could know which applications use my internet bandwidth because I experience slow download speed even though I only use a tab which is download.

Gnome system monitor doesn't give me that list but it gives me a chart of my total upload and download speeds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use with `nethogs` tool. it is a command line tool

for example `sudo nethogs wlan0` will give you the usage of wlan0...